# ensure all tags are closed php

Tags: php, html

I have a `<textarea>` where I am allowing user content to be submitted. I would like to allow a couple tags such as `<b>`, `<i>`,`<blockquote>`, and `<del>`. However, since the content will be displayed in the page, I have to ensure that there are no unclosed tags.

I know I can use `strip_tags($textarea, '<b><i><blockquote><del>')`, but how can I then ensure that all the remaining tags are properly closed?

Comment: just an idea, use BBCode and translate this to HTML, then you have the full controll over the tags...

Comment: I would be willing to use BBCode, but I would still want to ensure they were closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php). It will clean and sanitize your HTML.

This comment, on php.net, address your problem and shows how to solve it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.examples.basic.php#89334

> Cleaning an html fragment (OO support
>   seems to half-arsed for now)
>
> This will ensure all tags are closed,
>   without adding any html/head/body tags
>   around it.

```
<?php
$tidy_config = array( 
  'clean' => true, 
  'output-xhtml' => true, 
  'show-body-only' => true, 
  'wrap' => 0, 
); 

$tidy = tidy_parse_string($html_fragment, $tidy_config, 'UTF8'); 
$tidy->cleanRepair(); 
echo $tidy; 
?>
```

Comment: Been trying Tidy out for a while. It's not perfect, but it's ver very good.

Answer (score 0):

The DOMDocument extension provides an API for manipulating HTML DOM structures and ought to be worth looking at for this.

Answer (score 0):

You really want to use a proper HTML filtering library, such as [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), especially since you're planning to use the submitted content for displaying styles. HTMLPurifier considers both attributes, css and other inline styles to avoid XSS, and will also attempt to make sense (by using Tidy as already suggested) of your HTML and clean up any missing tags (to ensure that the resulting fragment is XHTML compliant).

I don't think that Tidy will attempt to remove any evil XSS segments.

Comment: Do you have any experience with HTML Purifier? It seems like this is what I should do, but I'm looking for a quick and dirty how-to on how to allow certain tags and add rel=nofollow to links.